# How to make child div get expanded in two div without expanding its parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to keep header height constant while box on the right side of the header should get expanded as a I keep adding multi line content. Please see attached image [image]

My Code

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  background: #1c1d1f;
}

.rightbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #efefef;
}

.content {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="rightbar">content inside box</div>
  <div class="content">
    some content goes here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer content goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scrollbar appear in your right-side bar then you should try to use `overflow-y:auto;`

Like below:

```
.rightbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
  background:#efefef;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```